# show images in textarea

Tags: java, html

I have to implement gtalk like chat application using UDP in java.
i have written server and client programs to send/receive text,smileys(compulsory).

the problem is that image can't be displayed in text area.i want to display both the incoming text and smiley in a control.Text area won't work. please suggest some other control...

Comment: You want to implement the images for the smileys? Why not simply add the respective code in the textarea and then call on the image once its posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [javax.swing.JTextPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html)

Check [TextSamplerDemo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TextSamplerDemo)

**You can find plenty of examples here:**

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TextPaneSample.htm

**Chat window using JTextPane no images though:**

[Java JTextPane JScrollPane Display Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741598/java-jtextpane-jscrollpane-display-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try a `div` with a [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.contentEditable) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the unicode character for a "White Smiling Face" and a font that supports this character? Then you don't need to worry about images at all.

The unicode for white smiling face is \u263A

If you browser is using a font that supports it, you'll see it here: ☺