# How to have a Scrollable JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextpane

I would like to have a JTextPane that have scroll bar, how can I do so ? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To insert a scroll bar on your new JTextPane, just use a JScrollPane:

```
JTextPane txt = new JTextPane();

JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(txt);
```

JTextPane API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html

JScrollPane API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

If you have some issues, take a look at this SO question : 
[Java JTextPane JScrollPane Display Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741598/java-jtextpane-jscrollpane-display-issue)

Or take a look at: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/30283

Answer (score 6):

Wrap it into a JScrollPane. Read the [swing tutorial about scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).

Answer (score 4):

Just put the JTextPane in a JScrollPane.

```
public class SomeFrame
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame( );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tp);
    frame.getContentPane().add( sp );

    frame.pack( );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to add a scrollbar to the TextBox

```java
JEditorPane edtDTWinfo = new JEditorPane();
edtDTWinfo.setEditable(false);
edtDTWinfo.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 2));
edtDTWinfo.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
JScrollPane spEditor = new JScrollPane(edtDTWinfo,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
spEditor.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 300);
```

Add component "spEditor" to the JPanel

Answer (score 0):

Before this just add a ScrollPane to ContentPane in Design and add EditopPane to ScrollPane as child

```
JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane)contentPane.getComponent(23);//this is in my hierarchy 23
JViewport vp = sp.getViewport();
JEditorPane ep = (JEditorPane)vp.getView();
```