# Adding a JscrollPane to a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I am Trying to add a JscrollPane to my JTextPane and it does not show up when i run it. I have searched the internet and most answers do not help at all.

This is how i implemented it in my code

```
    JTextPane t = new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(t);
    s.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    t.setBounds(10,50,60,70);
    s.setBounds(10,50,60,70);
    Pane.add(t);
    Pane.add(s);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a Scrollable JTextPane?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182473/how-to-have-a-scrollable-jtextpane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by getting rid of `t.setBounds(10,50,60,70);` and `s.setBounds(10,50,60,70);` and `Pane.add(t);`. A component can only reside within a single container, by calling `Pane.add(t)` you are removing the component from it's parent container (the `JScrollPane`).

Also, make sure you're using appropriate layout managers to manage your layouts (there's no need to call `setBounds`)

You might also like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot