# How to add working JScrollPane to JTextArea?

Tags: jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a problem with this code. At "   //Jūsu piedāvātais preču sortiments" I'm  trying to add JScrollPane into JTextArea. I have tried lots for methods, but no one of them works. Only thing what I can do is to add it but it will not work what ever I do. So, if someone have any idea how to do it, it would be greatly appreciate.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class otraForma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pieteikuma forma");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(355, 500)); 
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        komponenti(panel);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void komponenti(JPanel panel) {

        panel.setLayout(null);

        /*Šeit uzskaita visu formu
        * Tai skaitaa ari izmerus. Tos droši vien jāliek, lai autmātiski maina,
        * bet nezinu kā to izdarīt. Vēlāk arī pievinos krāsas vai dizainu.
        */

        //------------JTextField-------------//

        //Vārds
        JLabel vards = new JLabel("Vārds"); //ar JLabel izveido pāsu textu
        vards.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25); //ievieto mērogu (tas būs jāmaina)
        panel.add(vards); //pievieno viņu formai

        JTextField vards_texts = new JTextField(20); //tiek izveidots ievades laukums
        vards_texts.setBounds(100, 10, 240, 25);
        panel.add(vards_texts);

        //------------JTextField-------------//

        //Uzvārds
        JLabel uzvards = new JLabel("Uzvārds");
        uzvards.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        panel.add(uzvards);

        JTextField uzvars_texts = new JTextField(20);
        uzvars_texts.setBounds(100, 40, 240, 25);
        panel.add(uzvars_texts);

        //------------JTextField-------------//

        //E-pasts
        JLabel epasts = new JLabel("E-pasts");
        epasts.setBounds(10, 70, 80, 25);
        panel.add(epasts);

        JTextField epasts_texts = new JTextField(30);
        epasts_texts.setBounds(100, 70, 240, 25);
        panel.add(epasts_texts);

        //------------JComboBox-------------//

        //Vēlamais apmeklējuma datums
        JLabel datums = new JLabel("Apmeklējums");
        datums.setBounds(10, 100, 80, 25);
        panel.add(datums);

        JComboBox datums_drop_menesi = new JComboBox();
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Janvāris");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Februāris");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Marts");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Aprīlis");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Maijs");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Jūnis");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Jūlijs");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Augusts");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Septembris");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Oktobris");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Novembris");
        datums_drop_menesi.addItem("Decembris");
             //datums_drop_menesi.setMaximumRowCount(datums_drop_menesi.getModel().getSize());
        datums_drop_menesi.setBounds(100, 100, 115, 25); //(* , *, garums, *)
        panel.add(datums_drop_menesi);

        JComboBox datums_drop_dienas = new JComboBox();
        for(int i=1;i<=31;i++) {
            datums_drop_dienas.addItem(new Integer(i));
        }
        datums_drop_dienas.setBounds(225, 100, 115, 25);
        panel.add(datums_drop_dienas);

        //------------JCheckBox-------------//

        //Vai nepieciešams pavilijons?
        JLabel pavilijons = new JLabel("Vai nepieciešams pavilijons?");
        pavilijons.setBounds(10, 130, 170, 25);
        panel.add(pavilijons);

        JCheckBox pavilijons_check1 = new JCheckBox();
        pavilijons_check1.setText("Jā");
        pavilijons_check1.setBounds(225, 130, 40, 25);
        panel.add(pavilijons_check1);

        JCheckBox pavilijons_check2 = new JCheckBox();
        pavilijons_check2.setText("Nē");
        pavilijons_check2.setBounds(300, 130, 40, 25);
        panel.add(pavilijons_check2);

        ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup(); //nodrošina to, ka tikai, ka viens check box
        group1.add(pavilijons_check1);         //ir nospiests vienlaiciigi
        group1.add(pavilijons_check2);

        //------------JCheckBox-------------//

        //Vai nepieciešams tirgus galds?
        JLabel galds = new JLabel("Vai nepieciešams tirgus galds?");
        galds.setBounds(10, 160, 180, 25);
        panel.add(galds);

        JCheckBox galds_check1 = new JCheckBox();
        galds_check1.setText("Jā");
        galds_check1.setBounds(225, 160, 40, 25);
        panel.add(galds_check1);

        JCheckBox galds_check2 = new JCheckBox();
        galds_check2.setText("Nē");
        galds_check2.setBounds(300, 160, 40, 25);
        panel.add(galds_check2);

        ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
        group2.add(galds_check1);          
        group2.add(galds_check2);


        //------------JCheckBox-------------//

        //Vai nepieciešams elektrības pieslēgums?
        JLabel elektriba = new JLabel("Vai nepieciešama elektrība?");
        elektriba.setBounds(10, 190, 180, 25);
        panel.add(elektriba);

        JCheckBox elektriba_check1 = new JCheckBox();
        elektriba_check1.setText("Jā");
        elektriba_check1.setBounds(225, 190, 40, 25);
        panel.add(elektriba_check1);

        JCheckBox elektriba_check2 = new JCheckBox();
        elektriba_check2.setText("Nē");
        elektriba_check2.setBounds(300, 190, 40, 25);

        ButtonGroup group3 = new ButtonGroup();
        group3.add(elektriba_check1);          
        group3.add(elektriba_check2);
        panel.add(elektriba_check2);

        //------------JTextField-------------//

        //Jūsu piedāvātais preču sortiments
        JLabel piedavajums = new JLabel("Jūsu piedāvātais preču sortiments.");
        piedavajums.setBounds(10, 220, 325, 25);
        panel.add(piedavajums);

        JTextArea piedavajums_texts = new JTextArea();
        piedavajums_texts.setBounds(10, 250, 300, 100);
        piedavajums_texts.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        piedavajums_texts.setLineWrap(true);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(piedavajums_texts);
        sp.getVerticalScrollBar();
        sp.setBounds(300, 250, 20, 100);

        panel.add(sp);
        panel.add(piedavajums_texts);

        //------------JButton-------------//

        //Beigt
        JButton atpakal = new JButton("Info");
        atpakal.setBounds(10, 425, 80, 25); // x-ass, y-ass. texkta bloka garums/augstums
        panel.add(atpakal);

        //Importēt
        JButton imports = new JButton("Importēt");
        imports.setBounds(123, 425, 100, 25);
        panel.add(imports);

        //Beigt
        JButton beigt = new JButton("Beigt");
        beigt.setBounds(255, 425, 80, 25);
        panel.add(beigt);

    }

}
```

Comment: Doy ou want your JTerxtArea to scoll the content?

Comment: Yes. Thats the plan. But it just dont work...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182473/how-to-have-a-scrollable-jtextpane

Comment: well.. I tried but only thing what I could found was that I need use frame.getContentPane().add( sp ); . It kind of work, but all my other stuff is gone. I need to add exactly to  JTextArea in that region. .